# What is a GitHub App's Integration ID in ghinstallation?

Tags: go, github

I am trying to create a GitHub App in Golang by using a library named [ghinstallation](https://github.com/bradleyfalzon/ghinstallation). As the description showed below, Integration ID and Installation ID are required.

```
// Wrap the shared transport for use with the integration ID 1 authenticating with installation ID 99.
itr, err := ghinstallation.NewKeyFromFile(tr, 1, 99, "2016-10-19.private-key.pem")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I think the Installation ID is exactly the ID appears in the URL(`https://github.com/settings/installations/:installation_id`). 
However, I've no idea what the Integration ID is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GitHub App Integration ID is the ID of your GitHub App. You can find it in the "About" section in the "General" tab of your GitHub App.